# Is Android SOS being used as privilege escalation or settings bypass?

Tags: android, mobile, phone, privilege-escalation, mobile-app

I have been getting random SOS countdowns triggered on my phone. Every time this happens, a pop-up appears telling me that unknown numbers have been temporarily unblocked. The most recent instance was immediately followed by a call from a "Private Number". I declined that call and immediately restored blocking of unknown numbers. But is it possible:

1. Someone has remote access to my phone and specifically needs me to receive a phone call from them (e.g. crypto locker, blackmail or grabbing my voice)
2. Someone has limited access sufficient to trigger SOS but not much else, e.g. via an app I installed?

[image: screenshot of call history]

Comment: "*I have been getting random SOS countdowns triggered on my phone.*" probably your phone got its power button accidentally pressed 5 times. Assuming your phone is Samsung based on the screenshot, check the phone's settings on Settings - Safety and emergency - Emergency SOS.

Comment: Yep I saw that during my googling. Tbh it's possible this is just random error. But the coincidental timing of the Private Number call spooked me this time. For now I've completely disabled the functionality